# AJAX : Pass an image and data through Single AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to pass some text data and file through one ajax code

Here is my code's index.php :-

```
<?php 
session_start();
if (@$_SESSION['user']!=true) {
    echo "<script>window.alert('You are not login.');</script>";
    echo "<script>window.open('login.php','_self');</script>";
}
else {
  include_once '../connection.php';
  $uid=$_SESSION['id'];
  $query=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `register` WHERE `id`='$uid'");
  $row=mysqli_fetch_array($query);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>    
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Karthikeyan K">
    <title>POST</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS file -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        padding: 45px;
      }
      footer {
        margin: 10px 0;
      }

      .photo {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
      }
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mentionsInput.css">
    <style type="text/css">
      #status-overlay {
          height: 100%;
          width: 100%;
          background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50);
          position: fixed;
          top: 0;
          left: 0;
          z-index: 99999;
          overflow: hidden;
      }
      #highlight-textarea {
        background: #fff;
      }

      .form-control:focus {
          box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #3399ff;
          outline: 0;
      }
      h2 {
        font-size: 20px;
      }
    </style>
    <style>
      #upload_button {
          display: none;

          border: 0px;
          background: linear-gradient(180deg, #f44, #811);
          border-radius: 5px;

          color: #fff;

          padding: 5px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="status-overlay" style="display: none"></div>
                  <form method="POST" class="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Post title..."><br>
                  <div id="highlight-textarea">
                    <textarea onclick="highlight();" name="postText" class="form-control postText mention" cols="10" rows="8" placeholder="What&#039;s going on?" dir="auto"></textarea>
                  </div><br>
                  <select class="form-control" name="type" id="type" required>
                    <option value="">Choose Post Type</option>
                    <option value="Closet">Closet</option>
                    <option value="Follower">Follower</option>
                    <option value="Group">Group</option>
                  </select><br>
                  <p><button id="upload_button">Click here to select file</button></p>
                    <p><input  id="upload_input" name="upfile" type="file"/></p>
                </div>
                <input type="button" value="Post" class="btn btn-primary pull-right postMention">
              </form>
      <!-- Bootstrap Script file -->
      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

      <script src='https://cdn.rawgit.com/jashkenas/underscore/1.8.3/underscore-min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
        <script src='js/lib/jquery.elastic.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mentionsInput.js"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('textarea').on('click', function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
        $(document).on('click', function (e) {
                $("#status-overlay").hide();
                $("#highlight-textarea").css('z-index','1');
                $("#highlight-textarea").css('position', '');
        });
      });
      function highlight()
      {
        $("#status-overlay").show();
        $("#highlight-textarea").css('z-index','9999999');
        $("#highlight-textarea").css('position', 'relative');
      }


      $(document).ready(function(){

      $('.postMention').click(function() {
          $('textarea.mention').mentionsInput('val', function(text) {
            var post_text = text;
            if(post_text != '')
            {
                //post text in jquery ajax
            var post_data = "text="+encodeURIComponent(post_text);
            var val1 = $('#title').val();
            var val2 = $('#type').val();  
            //var val3 = $('#upload_input');    
            //var post_title = $('#title').val();

            var form = new FormData(document.getElementById('.postMention'));
            //append files
            var file = document.getElementById('upload_input').files[0];
            if (file) {   
                form.append('upload_input', file);
            }

            $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  data: post_data+'&title='+val1+'&type='+val2+'&upload_input='+form,
                  url: 'ajax/post.php',
                  success: function(msg) {
                   if(msg.error== 1)
                   {
                    alert('Something Went Wrong!');
                   } else {

                    $("#post_updates").prepend(msg);
                    //reset the textarea after successful update
                    $("textarea.mention").mentionsInput('reset');

                   }
                  }
            });

            } else {
                alert("Post cannot be empty!");
            }

          });
        });


      //used for get users from database while typing @..
        $('textarea.mention').mentionsInput({
          onDataRequest:function (mode, query, callback) {
            $.getJSON('ajax/get_users_json.php', function(responseData) {
              responseData = _.filter(responseData, function(item) { return item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) > -1 });
              callback.call(this, responseData);
            });
          }
        });

      });
      </script>
  </body>
</html>

<?php } ?>
```

here's a code of my php file to insert data into database ajax/post.php
                                           .                                                               .                                                                 .                                                      .

```
<?php
session_start();
if (@$_SESSION['user']!=true) {
    echo "<script>window.alert('You are not login.');</script>";
    echo "<script>window.open('login.php','_self');</script>";
}
else {
  include_once '../../connection.php';
  $uid=$_SESSION['id'];
  $query=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `register` WHERE `id`='$uid'");
  $row=mysqli_fetch_array($query);



if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST['text']) && $_POST['text'] != '')
{
    include '../config/config.php';
    $user = $uid; //w3lessons demo user
  $postid=mt_rand();
    $text = strip_tags($_POST['text']); //clean the text
  $title= $_POST['title'];
  $type= $_POST['type'];

  define('FIRST_MATCH_GROUP', 1);
  preg_match_all("/@\[(.+)\]/U", $text, $tags); // Value under @[]

  $tags = implode(',', $tags[FIRST_MATCH_GROUP]);
  $upfile_name = $_FILES['upload_input']['name'];
  $upfile_size =$_FILES['upload_input']['size'];
  $upfile_tmp =$_FILES['upload_input']['tmp_name'];
  $upfile_type=$_FILES['upload_input']['type'];
  $upfile_t = explode(".", $_FILES["upload_input"]["name"]);
  $upfile_name = mt_rand() . '.' . end($upfile_t);

    if($upfile_type == "image/jpg" && $upfile_type == "image/png" && $upfile_type == "image/jpeg" && $upfile_type == "video/mp4"){
      echo "<script>window.alert('extension not allowed, please choose a JPG or PNG or MP4 file.');</script>";
    }
    else {
      if($upfile_size > 10485760){
        echo "<script>window.alert('File size must be Less 10 MB');</script>";
      }
      else {
          move_uploaded_file($upfile_tmp,"../../uploads/".$upfile_name);
        $DB->query("INSERT INTO posts(post_id,title,content,user_id,type,tags,image) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", array($postid,$title,$text,$user,$type,$tags,$upload_input));
     ?>
     <div class="media">
    <div class="media-left">
      <img src="https://cdn.w3lessons.info/logo.png" class="media-object" style="width:60px">
    </div>
    <div class="media-body">
      <h4 class="media-heading">w3lessons</h4>
      <p><?php echo getMentions($text); ?></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <?php
} } } else {
    echo "1"; //Post Cannot be empty!
}


function getMentions($content)
{
    global $DB;
    $mention_regex = '/@\[([0-9]+)\]/i'; //mention regrex to get all @texts

    if (preg_match_all($mention_regex, $content, $matches))
    {
        foreach ($matches[1] as $match)
        {
            $match_user =$DB->row("SELECT * FROM register WHERE id=?",array($match));


            $match_search = '@[' . $match . ']';
            $match_replace = '<a target="_blank" href="' . $match_user['profile_img'] . '">@' . $match_user['first_name'] . '</a>';

            if (isset($match_user['id']))
            {
                $content = str_replace($match_search, $match_replace, $content);
            }

        }
    } 
    return $content;
}
}?>
```

When i submit form data was passing at my php page but images index is goes undefined...

Answer (score 0):

change the way you pass data in request

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

      $('.postMention').click(function() {
          $('textarea.mention').mentionsInput('val', function(text) {
            var post_text = text;
            if(post_text != '')
            {
               var formData = new FormData($('.form')[0]);
               formData.append('text',encodeURIComponent(post_text));
               $.ajax({
                 url: 'ajax/post.php',
                 type: 'POST',
                 data: formData,
                 success: function (data) {
                    if(msg.error== 1)
                    {
                        alert('Something Went Wrong!');
                    } else {

                    $("#post_updates").prepend(msg);
                    //reset the textarea after successful update
                    $("textarea.mention").mentionsInput('reset');
                  }

                },
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false
              });
            } else {
                alert("Post cannot be empty!");
            }

          });
    });
```

and input name

```
<input  id="upload_input" name="upload_input" type="file"/>
```

Comment: getting error in php file my first statement not working 

That is :

if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST['text']) && $_POST['text'] != '')

Comment: add this line before ajax req  formData.append('text',encodeURIComponent(post_text));

Comment: Ohh i'm sorry that was error off server side file i had solved that

one more problem is how to concatenate post_text with formData to pass both to ajax/post.php?

Comment: formData.append('post_text',encodeURIComponent(post_text))

Comment: after adding this my data in postText field will replace blank space with %20